# How to change structure of json data and add new fields on python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to the structure of my json data, but I cant get my head around it. This is the sample of the data that I have

```
[<OldSample {u'counter_name': u'cpu_util', u'user_id': u'7bffa12f482840c7801e3e01e160c8cb', u'resource_id': u'ef392c3d-74fa-43fe-87c5-7e117b6d8a09', u'timestamp': u'2015-07-01T15:13:55', u'counter_volume': 0.034999999999999996, u'resource_metadata': {u'ramdisk_id': u'None', u'flavor.vcpus': u'1', u'OS-EXT-AZ.availability_zone': u'nova', u'display_name': u'ubuntu-io', u'flavor.id': u'596642d8-0813-4ae9-aec4-0105fdf05761', u'status': u'active', u'ephemeral_gb': u'0', u'flavor.name': u'm1.small.io', u'disk_gb': u'20', u'kernel_id': u'None', u'image.id': u'5776a360-0953-4c93-931d-a6e3616fb8dc', u'flavor.ram': u'2048', u'host': u'9fa544f5c47569db21d50bc6c0765296316a56bd6baf6b04d705686a', u'flavor.ephemeral': u'0', u'image.name': u'ubuntu-io', u'image_ref_url': u'link': u"[{'href': 'link', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]", u'cpu_number': u'1', u'flavor.disk': u'20', u'root_gb': u'20', u'name': u'instance-000000d3', u'memory_mb': u'2048', u'instance_type': u'596642d8-0813-4ae9-aec4-0105fdf05761', u'vcpus': u'1', u'image_ref': u'5776a360-0953-4c93-931d-a6e3616fb8dc', u'flavor.links': u"[{'href': 'link', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]"}, u'source': u'openstack', u'counter_unit': u'%', u'recorded_at': u'2015-07-01T15:13:56.006000', u'project_id': u'1670f0e56fb6421cb83d81b60b149c04', u'message_id': u'ca8ea466-2003-11e5-a764-002590e64886', u'counter_type': u'gauge'}>, <OldSample {u'counter_name': u'cpu_util', u'user_id': u'7bffa12f482840c7801e3e01e160c8cb', u'resource_id': u'0c8b6b26-3340-41e3-ac8b-cc38f15d3570', u'timestamp': u'2015-07-01T15:08:32', u'counter_volume': 5.4399999999999995, u'resource_metadata': {u'ramdisk_id': u'None', u'flavor.vcpus': u'1', u'OS-EXT-AZ.availability_zone': u'nova', u'display_name': u'kalman_instance', u'flavor.id': u'1', u'status': u'active', u'ephemeral_gb': u'0', u'flavor.name': u'm1.tiny', u'disk_gb': u'1', u'kernel_id': u'None', u'image.id': u'1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'flavor.ram': u'512', u'host': u'25aa71ded460ea9d4bf52e1aac34017691699cb5e4e389704d738bed', u'flavor.ephemeral': u'0', u'image.name': u'cirros', u'image_ref_url': u'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/images/1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'image.links': u"[{'href': 'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/images/1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]", u'cpu_number': u'1', u'flavor.disk': u'1', u'root_gb': u'1', u'name': u'instance-0000013c', u'memory_mb': u'512', u'instance_type': u'1', u'vcpus': u'1', u'image_ref': u'1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'flavor.links': u"[{'href': 'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/flavors/1', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]"}, u'source': u'openstack', u'counter_unit': u'%', u'recorded_at': u'2015-07-01T15:08:32.459000', u'project_id': u'1670f0e56fb6421cb83d81b60b149c04', u'message_id': u'09b5173e-2003-11e5-ac7a-002590e64b12', u'counter_type': u'gauge'}>]
```

Which I want to change in something like this

```
 message: {
      columns: [
        ["y": 0.043, "x": "2015-06-30T15:53:55"],
        ["y": 0.045, "x": "2015-06-30T15:53:55"]
      ]
```

Here is my code,

```
def clean_Json(data):
  for each in data:
    timestamp = each.timestamp
    volume =  each.counter_volume
    i = json.dumps({'x': timestamp, 'y': volume})
    print i

clean_Json(data)
```

Result:

```
{"y": 4.101666666666667, "x": "2015-04-10T15:18:18"}
{"y": 5.471666666666666, "x": "2015-04-10T14:48:18"}
```

The problem is that

**1.** there is no comma at the end of each line.
**2.** when I try to add Square brackets I get syntax error.

I cant seem to move forward from **json.dumps({'x': timestamp, 'y': volume})**

Comment: Structure you want to achieve isn't a JSON (JSON objects use `{}` brackets, not `[]`), is this really what you want?

Comment: @Tupteq I am afraid so, actually what I want to achieve with this is something that I can plug in EON charts in pubnub http://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/chart/spline/

Comment: So, you probably shouldn't use JSON library, because you don't need a JSON. Consider creating your own formatting using idioms like `','.join(items)`.

Comment: @Tupteq Can you give me an example? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the above problem:

```
thing = {}
msg = {}
cols = []


for row in data:
    col = {}
    col = {"x": row.timestamp, "y": row.counter_volume}
    cols.append(col)

msg['columns'] = cols

thing['message'] = msg

print json.dumps(thing, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
result_rows = []
for row in data:
    # Format output as desired
    formatted = """["y": %0.3f, "x": "%s"]""" % (row.counter_volume, row.timestamp)

    #Append to result list
    result_rows.append(formatted)

# Pythonic way to join strings putting something (comma+newline) between items
print(',\n'.join(result_rows))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but here is another error for row in data.split("\n"):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'--- this is indeed a pain

Comment: If your data is already list (not string), then you don't need to split it, just use it directly `for row in data:`.

Comment: Now It raises an attribute error,  File "data.py", line 57, in <module>
    row = row.strip()
 raise AttributeError(k)
AttributeError: strip

Comment: It looks like you input data isn't string, of so, what exactly it is? Can you provide some real data, because content you provided in question converts without any problem.

Comment: provided complete data above

Comment: Nope, Type Error this time, it is strange that I keep getting same kind of error with completely different solutions the error this time for row in re_x.findall(data):
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Did you try to copy and paste my code to file? You may check type of `data` by putting `print(type(data))`. Maybe it'll tell something.

Comment: Yes, the data type is list  answer to print(type(data)) <type 'list'>, When I try to put the atual data it starts to throw errors, Did you look at the actual data I provided above?

Comment: Take a look now. I think I finally figured out what you meant.

Comment: Thankyou so much for trying to help me all the way. This problem is driving me crazy. It still throws errors TypeError: format requires a mapping, when I try your updated solution

Comment: It's hard to write a code without access to real data. I made so many mistakes :)
Check now. It seems to be quite simple although it was hard for me (and not only me) to understand your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, `[]` represent arrays, and `{}` represent objects. It is not possible to have an array with key-value pairs, like you have in your desired output for individual objects in the columns array. They are objects so they must be enclosed in `{}` only. You must implement your own string concatenation logic if you want square brackets for sure.

```
def get_clean_Json(data):
  return [{ "x": each['timestamp'], "y": each['counter_volume'] } for each in data]
```

Testing above code:

```
st = '[{"timestamp": "2015-06-30T15:53:55", "counter_volume": 0.043}, {"timestamp": "121", "counter_volume": 0.045}]'
data = json.loads(st)
j = get_clean_Json(data)

json.dumps({ 'message': { 'columns': j } })
```

Output:

`{"message": {"columns": [{"y": 0.043, "x": "2015-06-30T15:53:55"}, {"y": 0.045, "x": "121"}]}}`

Comment: There is a stickler in the data [<OldSample, (see data example above first line)
and when I try your code above it gives me the error TypeError: 'OldSample' object has no attribute '__getitem__'